# Change actionBar color only in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am making a movie app and I want to change the action bar color to transparent **but only in a specific fragment**.

I thought about making an action bar style in theme.xml but I couldn't do it without changing the whole app action bar.

I thought about making a custom ToolBar and then assigning it with a back button but the action bar is showing with the custom ToolBar I made.

I am using MVVM.

I tried doing like the following but its changing the action bar color to the whole app instead of just this fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view =
        inflater.inflate(com.dapps.moviesmvvm.R.layout.movie_details_fragment, container, false)

    toolbar = view.findViewById<android.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)


    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    // Change the action bar to red for the **whole** application,not just the fragment.
    val actionbar = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
    actionbar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, android.R.color.holo_red_dark)));


    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name)




    return view
}
```

What is the best practice to change the action bar color only in this specific fragment ?

Thank you !

EDIT:

When trying to set the action bar to Color.Transparent, the color is changing to dark grey instead.

Comment: You need to revert it too when this fragment detached . probably in `onDestoyView` if you are using replace transactions further .

Comment: You need to change your action bar color back to normal in either `onDestroyView` of the fragment you are in or either in `onResume` of the next/prev fragment. 1st option is most likely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity

```
 fun supportActionBar(number: Int, title: String): Boolean {
    return when (number) {
        0 -> {
            setViewVisible(
                title,
                0,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.VISIBLE
            )
            true
        }
        1 -> {
            setViewVisible(
                title,
                1,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.GONE,
                View.VISIBLE,
                View.VISIBLE
            )
            true
        }
        
        else -> true
    }
}

 private fun setViewVisible(
    title: String,
    from: Int,
    imgToolbarLeft: Int,
    imgToolbarCancel: Int,
    txtToolbarDone: Int,
    viewToolbar: Int,
    imgToolbarMainMenu: Int,
    nav_view: Int
) {
    binding.include.txtToolbarName.text = title
    binding.include.txtToolbarDone.visibility = txtToolbarDone
    binding.include.imgToolbarLeft.visibility = imgToolbarLeft
    binding.include.imgToolbarCancel.visibility = imgToolbarCancel
    binding.include.imgToolbarMainMenu.visibility = imgToolbarMainMenu
    binding.include.viewToolbar.visibility = viewToolbar
    binding.navView.visibility = nav_view

when (from) {
        1 -> {
                                bindingMain.include.toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.holo_red_dark))

        }else{
```

bindingMain.include.toolbar.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.holo_red))
}
}

In Fragment

```
     override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (context as MainActivity).onSectionAttached(1, resources.getString(R.string.your_string))
    }
```